# Redirect USB Device To Virtual Machine Using Hyper-V As Host

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, redirection

So I have a machine that is running Hyper-V Server 2012R2 as the host (bare-metal hypervisor). I have a USB device that is attached to this machine and I need a virtual machine that is running on the host to have access to this USB device.

What application can I install on the Hyper-V machine using CMD or PowerShell that will allow me to passthrough the USB connection to one of its VM's?

Comment: I have VM's that have Windows Server 2012R2 and Windows 10 Pro

Comment: I got it to work on my Windows Server 2012R2 VM. Although the USB device in question is from a CyberPower UPS. I wanted my VM to be able to connect with the CyberPower PowerPanel software. This USB device is plugged into the machine that is hosting the VM's and not the machine that I'm using to connect to it. How would I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: It looks like "USB over IP" is the solution to my problem I'm having then. Just need to figure out what would work best for me now.

*Silex link is broken by the way.

Comment: Also see 3rd update in my answer.

Comment: You mean that feature that EVERY other hypervisor natively supports without hacks?

Comment: Only reason I use hyper-v is because my work is a Microsoft shop....

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of solutions that allow for USB over ethernet/ip which can be used to provide USB to virtualized clients on Hyper-V. To complete the picture, here are additional providers:

**VirtualHere**: Small Australian Company, which has the most flexible solution:
https://virtualhere.com/
I have used this on occasions where other solutions wont recognize a device, also this works out of the box on NAS devices (Synology etc.) and recently they have created an image for RaspberryPi3 and other devices. Clearly the best for Linux. But does not work for some MacOS versions (works on the most recent Mac Version 12)

The hardware solution from **IOGear - GUWIP204** (also available as a Hawking branded item, with older firmware and driver)
https://www.iogear.com/product/GUWIP204/

It is an old device but (still) available on Amazon:
http://amzn.to/2uNvz3Y

The IO gear device is very simple, but for some devices it just does not work. Additionally they have been slow to update the drivers and firmware, but have just released an update that allows it to work with *all* Mac OS, which is good for remote iOS development.

**Eltima software** USB Network Gate
Very complete USB sharing over network, very polished, and very reliable. But pricey, they keep updating which is good. I have used it extensively, but it adds up quickly if you have more than one server.
https://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/

Additionally Eltima have a cloud version which is on a monthly fee:
https://www.flexihub.com/

**FabulaTech** a London based company that does USB over IP, I have not tried them at all
http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network.html

Comment: +1 Eltima software. Pricey as you say, but no messing around. Worked out of the gate; a few others spent time messing with them, without solid successes.

Answer (score 6):

## Update 3:

You could try this software: http://www.incentivespro.com/hyper-v-usb.html

It has a free trial.

---

## Update 2:

According to [this website](http://windowsitpro.com/hyper-v/q-how-can-i-attach-usb-devices-hyper-v-virtual-machine):

> Hyper-V doesn't allow the pass-through of a USB-attached device on a
>   host to a VM. This would break the desired abstraction of the VM from
>   the hardware, and therefore stop VM mobility. however this doesn't
>   mean there are no solutions.
>
> This requires the use of third-party solutions that enable USB over
>   IP. The solutions work by having a physical server that has all the
>   USB devices connected to it and runs a service that enables the USB
>   devices to be accessed remotely over IP.
>
> The VMs then run a piece of client software that connects to the USB
>   device over IP, and it looks to the VM like a local USB device. The
>   benefit to these types of solutions is the VM can still be moved
>   between hosts without losing connectivity to the USB device. There are
>   many solutions available; among them are two I have seen used by my
>   customers:
>
> [Silex SX-2000U2](http://www.silexamerica.com/products/usb_device_connectivity/sx-2000u2.html)
> [Digi Anywhere USB](http://www.digi.com/products/usb/anywhereusb#overview)

---

## Update:

Looks like you're out of luck for the 10 Pro. MS page says:

> The virtual machine must have Remote Desktop Services enabled and **run
>   Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows 8.1 as the guest operating system**.

---

## Answer:

> Updated: May 20, 2015
>  Applies To: Windows Server 2012 R2
>
> You can give a virtual machine access to a computer’s local resources,
>   like a removable USB flash drive, when you use Virtual Connection
>   Manager (VMConnect). To make this happen, turn on enhanced session
>   mode on the Hyper-V host, use VMConnect to connect to the virtual
>   machine, and before you connect, choose the local resource that you
>   want to use.
>
> ---
>
> - Turn on enhanced session mode on Hyper-V host
>
> If your Hyper-V host runs Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, you might not have
>   to go through the following steps to turn on enhanced session mode.
>   It's turn on by default. But if your host runs Windows Server 2012 or
>   Windows Server 2012 R2, you must turn on enhanced session mode to use
>   it. It is turned off by default for those operating systems.
>
> To turn on enhanced session mode,
>
> 1) Connect to the computer that hosts the virtual machine.
>  2)
>   In Hyper-V Manager, select the host’s computer name.
>
> [image]
>
> 3) Select Hyper-V settings
>  [image]
>
> 4) Under Server, select Enhanced session mode policy.
>   [image]
>
> 5) Select the Allow enhanced session mode check box.
>   [image]
>
> 6) Under User, select Enhanced session mode.
>   [image]
>
> 7) Select the Allow enhanced session mode check box.
>
> 8) Click **OK**
>
> ---
>
> - Choose the local resource that you want to use
>
> You can choose a local resource like a printer, the clipboard or a
>   local drive that’s on the computer that you’re using to connect to the
>   VM.
>
> To select a local resource like a drive,
>
> 1) Open VMConnect.
>
> 2) Select the virtual machine that you want to connect to.
>
> 3) Click Show options.
>  [image]
>
> 4) Select **Local resources**
>   [image]
>
> 5) Click **More**.
>  [image]
>
> 6) Select the device that you want to use on the virtual machine and
>   click **Ok**.
>  [image]
>
> 7) Select Save my settings for future connections to this virtual
>   machine.
>  [image]
>
> 8) Click **connect**
>
> ---

**Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282274.aspx**

Comment: Is the USB sharing just for that session? I usually pass through a permanent like a scanner or UPS

Comment: ... Lame BTW every other hypervisor supports this, even virtual box...